# Is it dangerous to append search query to the base URL?

Tags: exploit, encoding, drupal, directory-traversal

I'm testing drupal website and I've noticed that search query gets appended to the base URL in the response, like so:

```
query: "hey ho: there"
http://www.baseurl.com/search/node/hey ho%3A there

query: "dis iz stackexchange!"
http://www.baseurl.com/search/node/dis iz stackexchange!

query: "@ # $ % ^ & * ( ) < > [ ]"
http://www.baseurl.com/search/node/%40 %23 %24 %25 ^ %26 * ( ) < > [ ]
```

1. Is this behavior dangerous?
2. Any guess why any of the '* ( ) < > [ ] !' aren't escaped?

Comment: Not inherently, but it could be a vulnerability depending on how the rest of your code handles that input. Do you escape the query text when showing it on your page? Have you parameterized your database queries?

Comment: @AronFoster I have no access to source code. I'm blind testing.

Comment: Well you haven't found an exploit here. Good luck elsewhere!